# how to prove the following propositional formula using semantic equivalence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-explanation

Hi Guys I am trying to prove the following formula using the rule below

```
¬p ⇔ q ≡ p ⇔ ¬q





A ∧ A ≡ A, A ∨ A ≡ A                                         idempotence
A ∧ B ≡ B ∧ A, A ∨ B ≡ B ∨ A                                 commutativity
A ∧ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∧ C , A ∨ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∨ C      associativity
A ∧ (A ∨ B) ≡ A, A ∨ (A ∧ B) ≡ A                             absorption
A ∧ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C )                            distributivity
A ∨ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C )                            distributivity
A ∧ (¬A) ≡ false, A ∨ (¬A) ≡ true                            negation
¬(¬A) ≡ A                                                    double negation
¬(A ∧ B) ≡ (¬A) ∨ (¬B), ¬(A ∨ B) ≡ (¬A) ∧ (¬B)               de Morgan
A ⇒ B ≡ (¬A) ∨ B                                             implication
A ⇔ B ≡ (A ⇒ B) ∧ (B ⇒ A)                                  bi-implication
```

This is what I have so far

```
¬p ⇔ q
```

≡ Bi-implication

```
(¬p ⇒ q ) ∧ (q ⇒ ¬p)
```

≡ Implication

```
(¬¬p v q ) ∧ (¬q v ¬p)
```

This is where I am stuck and not sure where to go next,

Comment: Thank you for actually posting the Logic you are using in a "help me prove this" logic question.  I wish all users did that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work both sides of the equation at the same time.  Since there is only 1 rule for $\iff$ and 1 rule for $\implies$, the first 2 steps can be guessed:

$$\begin{array} {c|ccc}
\lnot p \iff q & p \iff \lnot q \\
%
(\lnot p \implies q) \land  (q \implies \lnot p) & (p \implies \lnot q) \land (\lnot q \implies p) & & \text{bi-implication}\\
%
(\lnot \lnot p \lor q) \land  (\lnot q \lor \lnot p) & (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \land (\lnot \lnot q \lor p) & & \text{implication}\\
%
(p \lor q) \land  (\lnot q \lor \lnot p) & (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \land (q \lor p) & & \text{double negation}\\
%
\end{array}$$

Now there is just 1 rule left to establish the equivalence of both sides:

> Commutivity

Answer (score 2):

Using *double negation*, from:

> $(¬¬p \lor q ) \land (¬q \lor ¬p)$

to :

> $(p \lor ¬¬q ) \land (¬q \lor ¬p)$

and by *implication* again:

> > $(¬q \to p) \land (p \to ¬q)$.

Comment: wait sorry I don't think that works, because the order of the 2nd line seems wrong so (p∨¬¬q)∧(¬q∨¬p) i cannot use implication for (p∨¬¬q). Correct me if I am wrong. Also if i use implication for (¬q∨¬p) that would just give me (q→¬p)

Comment: @user5647516 - but $\lor$ is *commutative*; thus $(¬q∨¬p)$ is $(¬p∨¬q)$ and by implication; $(p \to \lnot q)$.